# Bitlocker Encryption will not complete, completely locks up

Tags: encryption, windows-11, bitlocker

I am trying to encrypt an external HDD with BitLocker, but for some reason the process crashed at 89.2%. I rebooted & removed and re-attached the disk (since bitlocker was completely locked up; the control panel section would not launch and manage-bde would hang and refuse even task manager killing it, making me think it's stuck on a locked I/O call. I cannot pause the encryption - the status windows immediately goes to "not responding" and I cannot browse the files on the device, it just infinitely loads until I remove the drive or reboot. It seems that when the encryption process launches it completely locks the drive up preventing anything else from accessing it. Bitlocker itself then locks up and no encryption is done. It just stays at 89.2% with "(Not Responding)" - if I click the non-functional "Pause" button a dozen or so times it will usually give me a "this isn't responding, I'm telling microsoft then killing it" dialogue but the disk still is not accessible via any means. Even manage-bde commands just hang and never return anything but the startup/intro text.

At this point I'm pretty sure I'm gonna have to blow the partition away but there's some data I'd like to recover if possible.

EDIT: It completely locks up ALL I/O processes in Windows. I tried using Explorer, the control panel, and other programs that required access to any disk and all of them failed to launch until I disconnected the drive, at which point everything that was stalled launched.

Edit 2: reposting on superuser from stackoverflow per suggestion.

[image: The Control Panel page completely dies]
[image: It never leaves 89.2% and stays non-responsive]
[image: manage-bde commands did NOTHING while this drive was plugged in]

Comment: "At this point I'm pretty sure I'm gonna have to blow the partition away" - You absolutely will have to do this and likely replace the disk, because, a healthy disk would not behave in the manner you describe,.

Comment: 1. Since it stopped close to the end, could the issue be due to lack of drive space? During encryption, there has to be both an original, unencrypted version of a file, as well as the encrypted one being made. 2. Likely, the only way to recover data would be from a full disk image made before beginning the process. 3. As mentioned above, check drive status and S.M.A.R.T. stats. That said, HDD's tend to fail bit-by-bit (no pun intended), and it might still  be usable (SSD's are more likely to become read-only or simply unusable).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I don’t think BitLocker works like that. While it rewrites every block, it does so, without having to recreate that block then delete the original block. However, with BitLocker being in the state I suspect the data won’t be accessible, if it was, the status command would have indicated a progress of the encryption process

Comment: When I plug it in and unlock it, it says it needs to repair the drive, but I can't because the drive freezes up almost immediately. I'm assuming a race condition between bitlocker and chkdsk at this point

Comment: @Chris - Your drive failed.

Comment: @Ramhound I blew away the partition, re-encypted it, and have loaded it about 20% full again so the disk itself is okay but I lost the trapped data.